# PSPP multi-response questions

Tags: statistics, limesurvey

We are totally new to PSPP and have a question.

We have imported data from LimeSurvey and that has imported fine but we have multiple response questions in the survey. 
After a lot of Googling we have found details about creating MRSets at http://www.gnu.org/software/pspp/manual/html_node/MRSETS.html but do not understand how we go about creating this.

Can anyone point us in the right direction
Rich

Comment: You'll get more interest in this question on stats.stackexchange.com. Also, if there is a PSPP user forum, you might ask there as well.

Comment: Thanks Robert, 
I'll take a look on the stats site
Cheers